# CSS Animation drops before going back up

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to have a navbar where the nav items gets pulled up and the logo shrinks as the user scrolls and back down as the user scroll back up.

but currently the nav items drop down before going up...and when it reverts it ends up at a different spot...

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
 <a href="#">James Jones</a>
  <ul class="nav-items">
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: ShorelinesScriptBold;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
  transition: all 1.0s ease;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #343434;
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0 0 -24px 0;*/
  margin: 0 0 -55px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #343434;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.shrink {
  font-family: 'Radley', serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-items {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;
  transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

.nav-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-items a {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items a:hover {
  color: #FFAED8;
}

.margin {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
     $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
     $('.nav-items').addClass('margin');
   } else {
     $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
     $('.nav-items').addClass('margin');
   }
});
```

JS FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/gkrtk8s3/4/

Comment: also...it acts more like the way I want it on jsfiddle...but locally it acts differently (using chrome)

Comment: when i scroll down...the nav items goes up a little first...
and when I scroll back up...the nav items stops at originial spot then drops a little afterwards

Comment: Did you mean to run `$('.nav-items').addClass('margin');` both times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why you are experiencing that bubbling movement on your menu bar is because you have

```
.nav-items {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease;/* Duplicate Transition. you already have a transition on your nav tag
  transition: all 1.0s ease; /* Duplicate Transition. you already have a transition on your nav tag
}
```

take out the two lines  `-webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease` and  `transition: all 1.0s ease;` from above

Note: tested in chrome Version 46.0.2490.71